# How to resize all text automatically based on device in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, typography

I am looking for a solution to automatically resize all texts based on device size without explicitely specifying for every element. Ex: Using class="display-4" displays same font size on both mobile and desktop. How to change dynamically ?

Comment: CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some relative font-sizes units, these are some here.

**CSS Units with relative length**

- vw (% of the viewport width)
- vh (% of the viewport height)
- vi (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's inline axis)
- vb (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's block axis)
- vmin (the smaller of vw or vh)
- vmax (the larger or vw or
  vh)

**Example:**

```
p {
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp Please also check this link.